# Weird file in terminal

Tags: bash, terminal

In the terminal, I regularly see weird files, like the one in this screenshot:

[image]

...and I have no idea, where they come from or what I did that created them.

Has anyone had the same issue?

If it's any help:

- it's often in git repositories and/or in folders that have a symlink source or destination. But that might just be, because I often work with these kinds of folders.
- This is in alacritty+WSL2. But the same file is present in git bash.

Comment: Does [this](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/337426/strange-file-with-impossible-name-in-my-home-directory) help by any chance?

Comment: Often odd file names happen because of syntax errors in commands one has run.  For example where a missed quote causes a ">" character that was supposed to be part of the string argument to be interpreted as a stdout redirection making the subsequent characters in the string to be interpreted as the file name to create.  Odd things like this can especially happen when you accidentally paste a long block of text into a shell window.

Comment: It looks like part of the confusion may be that `ls` is trying to add quotes/escapes/etc to the filename so that you could enter it in a shell command. Specifically, I think the entire `''$'\001'` prefix is just representing a single character (ASCII character code 1 aka control-A aka Start-of-header), and the rest is a single-quoted unrepresentable/invalid character. I suspect there's a bug in something that's using random garbage data as filenames.

Comment: Do you remember what you did yesterday around 19:47? Maybe running some script?

Comment: It could def be the result of running some script. I'll just go with that explanation and revisit the issue if it ever returns. Thanks guys

Comment: do not post text as images. See https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-should-i-not-upload-images-of-code-data-errors

Answer (score 0):

Seems like an issue with the character encoding in your terminal, or at least in one of them (git or wsl, which each may have different settings. if one is encoding it incorrectly, it'll be poorly formatted when viewing it in the other terminal as well)
I would try checking your locale settings w/ the command `locale` and make sure that the following values are present:

```
LC_ALL=en_US.UTF-8
LANG=en_US.UTF-8
```

if they aren't, add them to your bashrc or zshrc